# WPF - is it possible to change the opacity of a GridColumn?

Tags: wpf, animation, opacity

I want to have a grid of values with the headers in the left column and the databound results in the right column.  When the values change, I want them to fade in.  Is it possible to animate the Opacity of the right Column?  Or would I have to animated the Opacity of each separate TextBlock that's in each row of the right column?

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about the standard layout Grid panel, then no, you cannot set the opacity on it.

However, the better solution is to set it on each TextBlock, anyway. That way you could provide a single style, define the opacity animation there, and then all of your TextBlocks could use that style.